# How to use NHibernate's Session.Criteria with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

I'm trying to create a query using NHibernate and searching along multiple foreign keys:

The following code works when I'm only searching on one of the foreign keys:

```
            ICriteria query = Session.CreateCriteria<TblTeam>()
            .Add<TblTeam>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == teamName)
            .CreateCriteria<TblTeam>(x => x.TblSportsType)
            .Add<TblSportsType>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == sportsType);


        return query.UniqueResult<TblTeam>();
```

I need to search on two of the foreign keys so I created the following:

```
            ICriteria query = Session.CreateCriteria<TblTeam>()
            .Add<TblTeam>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == teamName)
            .CreateCriteria<TblTeam>(x => x.TblSportsType)
            .Add<TblSportsType>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == sportsType)
            .CreateCriteria<TblTeam>(x => x.TblSportsOrganization)
            .Add<TblSportsOrganization>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == sportsOrganization);

        return query.UniqueResult<TblTeam>();
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following error:

"could not resolve property: TblSportsOrganization of: site.Core.TblSportsType"

How would I have it take a "step back" as it were so I can add criteria to TblTeam and not TblSportsType?

Answer (score 1):

After talking with some people in IRC I've found an answer.  You need to hold on to the reference to the original ICriteria.  It should have been obvious.

```
            ICriteria query = Session.CreateCriteria<TblTeam>();
        query.Add<TblTeam>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == teamName);

        query.CreateCriteria<TblTeam>(x => x.TblSportsType)
            .Add<TblSportsType>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == sportsType);

        query.CreateCriteria<TblTeam>(x => x.TblSportsOrganization)
            .Add<TblSportsOrganization>(x => x.FldUrlSafeName == sportsOrganization);

        return query.UniqueResult<TblTeam>();
```